# How to trigger TweenMax Draggable event

Tags: javascript, draggable, gsap

I've a `draggable` bar, which can be drag horizontally. What i'm trying to do is, on page scroll Is it possible to trigger `draggable` event to drag?

I've provide the sample code below.

```
<div class="bar">
  <div id="handler"></div>
</div>
```

This is the initialisation.

```
Draggable.create("#handler",{
  type:"x",
  bounds: $('.bar')
});
```

Is it possible to do like this,

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  //move #handler horizontally
});
```

Please check the [codepen link](https://codepen.io/thanooshan/pen/abdover).

Answer (score 0):

**ZachSaucier** (GreenSock member) [helped me](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/24275-how-to-trigger-draggable-event/?tab=comments#comment-115315) on this case.

In order to achieve this, you should upgrade to [GSAP 3](https://greensock.com/gsap/) and use the [ScrollTrigger](https://greensock.com/scrolltrigger/) plugin.

```
const distObj = { x: 0, maxY: 0 };
let tween;
let ST;

function update() {
  // Update values as needed
  distObj.x = innerWidth - gsap.getProperty("#handler", "width");
  distObj.maxY = ScrollTrigger.maxScroll(window);

  // Kill off old things but keep the old progress
  let progress = 0;
  if(tween) {
    progress = tween.progress();
    ST.kill();
    drag.applyBounds({minX: 0, maxX: innerWidth});
  }

  // Create or recreate the tween and scroll trigger
  tween = gsap.fromTo("#handler", {x: 0}, {
    x: distObj.x,
    ease: "none",
    paused: true,
    overwrite: "auto"
  }).progress(progress);

  ST = ScrollTrigger.create({
    animation: tween,
    trigger: document.body,
    start: "top top",
    end: "bottom bottom",
    scrub: true
  });
}

update();
ScrollTrigger.addEventListener("refreshInit", update);

var drag = Draggable.create("#handler", {
  trigger: "#handler",
  type: "x",
  bounds: {minX: 0, maxX: innerWidth},
  onDrag: function() {
    const progress = this.x / distObj.x;
    tween.progress(progress);
    ST.scroll(progress * distObj.maxY);
  }
})[0];
```

Here is the updated [CodePen link.](https://codepen.io/thanooshan/pen/abdover) I hope this answer help someone. All credit goes to **ZachSaucier**.